# What format specifier do I use in C for dates?

Tags: c, date, format-specifiers

This is my code (I know using %d is wrong but I'm not sure what I am supposed to use):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
char charactername[] = "Ruby";
int age =18;
printf("Once upon a time there was girl named %s\n",charactername);
printf("%s was %d years old\n",charactername,age);

age =19;
int birthday = 22/07/2003;

printf("on %d she was born\n",birthday);
printf("On 22/07/2022 she will become %d",age);

return 0;
}
```

This is what the terminal gives me:

Once upon a time there was girl named Ruby

Ruby was 18 years old

on 0 she was born

On 22/07/2022 she will become 19

Comment: `int birthday = 22/07/2003;` What do you think this does?

Comment: `22/07/2003` is the same as `(22/07)/2003`.  `22/07` evaluates to `3`, and `3/2003` is zero.  So you've initialized `birthday` to `0`.  The problem is not in the format specifier.

Comment: Fascinating. `22/07/2003` is `0`, but `2003-07-22` is `1974` :D

Comment: Generally, consider using [`strftime()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strftime-wcsftime-strftime-l-wcsftime-l?view=msvc-170) to format time and date, which has its own set of format specifiers.

Comment: @YakovGalka, now try `2003-08-22`.  I suspect the result is not 1973 for "Ruby Octal". ;-)

Comment: It's tough on people with birthday's in August or September, or on the 8th or 9th of any month.  You can't use 08/09/2001 because they are invalid octal numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "date" type built in to C.  You can use strings for arbitray text; something like:

```
const char *birthday = "22/07/2003";
```

which you can print with a `%s` in the printf format

```
printf("on %s she was born\n",birthday);
```

Answer (score 3):

You would use a combination of [`struct tm`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ctime.3.html) and [`strftime`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html) from `time.h`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main( void )
{
  struct tm bdate = { .tm_year=(2003 - 1900), .tm_mday = 22, .tm_mon = 6 };
  char datebuf[11] = {0};
  
  strftime( datebuf, sizeof datebuf, "%d/%m/%Y", &bdate );
  printf( "bdate = %s\n", datebuf );
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./bdate
bdate = 22/07/2003
```

Comment: Note: Since [May 2017](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emma_Morano), looks like everybody alive now born on/after 1900, so for those of us, `.tm_year >= 0`.